# How do I do this join without including ItemID in the group by?

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I am trying to find the sum of each order then group by the order ID.  I had to use items.ItemID to join the 2 tables but I cannot get the sum of each order if I place ItemID in the group by statement.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Items.ItemID, Sum(Items.Price) AS SumPrice, Format(SumPrice*1.06,"Currency") AS TotalPrice
FROM Orders, Items
WHERE Items.ItemID=Orders.ItemID
GROUP BY OrderID;
```

I got the error "Your query does not include "ItemID" as part of an aggregate function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the SQL group can have multiple items.ItemId values. You need to specify which ItemId you want from the group by setting MAX(items.itemId) or MIN (items.ItemId) (or AVG or SUM, etc.).
or remove Items.Itemid from your select statement:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Sum(Items.Price) AS SumPrice, 
Format(SumPrice*1.06,"Currency") AS TotalPrice FROM Orders, Items WHERE 
Items.ItemID=Orders.ItemID GROUP BY OrderID;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three options:

1. Remove `ItemID` in the `SELECT` clause. From your schema, it is not clear if there are multiple rows for the same `OrderID`.
2. Include `ItemID` in the `SELECT` clause. All columns/fields must be in the `GROUP BY` or use an aggregate function such as `Count` or `Max`.
3. Use a subquery that has the `GROUP BY` and return `ItemID` at the outer layer. This is primarily useful for returning extra information from related columns that you do not want to include in the `GROUP BY`.

Example for #2

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID,
       Items.ItemID,
       Sum(Items.Price) AS SumPrice,
       Format(Sum(Items.Price)*1.06,"Currency") AS TotalPrice
FROM Orders JOIN Items ON Items.ItemID = Orders.ItemID
GROUP BY OrderID, ItemID;
```

Example for #3

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID,
       Orders.ItemID,
       -- Use the count from subquery to get SumPrice
       Orders.CountOrderID * Items.Price AS SumPrice,
       Format(Orders.CountOrderID * Items.Price,"Currency") AS TotalPrice
       -- Optional: include extra info from Items
FROM (
    -- Subquery with GROUP BY
    SELECT Orders.OrderID,
           Orders.ItemID,
           Count(Orders.OrderID) AS CountOrderID
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY Orders.OrderID, Orders.ItemID
    ) AS Orders JOIN Items ON Items.ItemID = Orders.ItemID;
```